# Can we smell in dreams?

Tags: perception, sleep, dreams

I'm interested in whether people can smell in their dreams.
Do people really experience smell in their dreams?
For example, if I dream of smelling a flower, will I feel the smell, too?

**Is there any research on whether people can smell in dreams?**

Comment: On it's face this is an interesting question (with a great answer) I think the problem with the question is the lack of (apparent) prior research. I haven't downvoted but I'm sure that's why others have

Comment: on 7/14/2013 i was sleeping during the day[I work at night] i know i was still sleeping
and could smell a cake being baked almost like pound cake smell.It filled my bedroom and then i woke up and could still smell this baking cake.I Thought to myself who could be here
baking?[I live alone] I went into the Kitchen and the smell was gone and no one was in the house but me.

Comment: I have awoken twice in the last week and i can smell stewed tea in my bedroom, wife had left for work 2 hours previous and does not like hot drinks!freaking me out...........no ketle warm,or windows open etc..cant work it out.....Sean

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Antonio, Nielsen and Doneri (1998) provide one assessment of self-reported  prevalence of smell in dreams. To quote the abstract (my bolding):

> Although numerous studies have investigated the content of 
>   laboratory  and home dream reports, surprisingly little  is  known
>   about the prevalence of various sensory modes in  dreams. 49 men and
>   115 women completed a battery of questionnaires and kept a home dream
>   diary for two to three consecutive weeks. Retrospective responses to 
>   the questionnaire indicate that  **approximately  33 %  of  men and 40% 
>   of  women recalled having experienced sensations of  smell  or taste in
>   their dreams**. A  total  of  3372 dream reports were collected and
>   scored for  unambiguous references to  auditory,  olfactory,  and 
>   gustatory experiences. Auditory  experiences were reported in 
>   approximately  53%  of  all  dream reports. **Olfactory  and gustatory
>   sensations occurred in  approximatdy 1 % of all dream reports.** A 
>   significantly greater percentage of women than men reported one or
>   more dreams containing references to olfactory sensations. The results
>   lend support to  previous studies which have shown that a variety of
>   sensory experiences, although relatively  rare, can occur in dreams.

There is still the question about whether self-reports are trustworthy, and how you define a smell experience in a dream that is most likely not generated by external stimuli. Antonio and colleagues go on to discuss some of these issues:

> That  the more infrequent modalities of  smell and taste occur at all
>   in dream reports is an important indication of the representational
>   capacities of dreaming-and  probably of  imagery more generally. The
>   finding  is consistent with  recent research showing the existence of
>   imagery in both olfactory (Carrasco &  Ridout, 1997; Lyman & McDaniel,
>   1986) and gustatory (Drummond,  1995) modalities. Although  some
>   researchers take the position that olfactory imagery is not possible
>   (Herz & Engen, 1996), the spontaneous occurrence of olfactory imagery
>   in  dreams may differ  from "willful"  olfactory imagery that may
>   occur upon instruction during  the waking state. For  instance, limbic
>   structures which  might  yield  such spontaneous occurrences during
>   dreams may not be operational during the waking state. Nevertheless,
>   it  is  likely  that  the  relatively rare occurrence of  these
>   modalities during dreaming is not  because their  representation is 
>   beyond imaginal capacity. Rather, either such sensations are not
>   usually spontaneously  generated during dreaming, i.e., are not a
>   necessary component of dreaming's supposed memory/adaptational
>   functions, or they depend upon external sensory stimuli to trigger
>   them. However, sensory triggers may be selectively blocked at  the
>   thalamic level by the raised afferent thresholds of REM sleep (e.g.,
>   Steriade, 1994). Of  course, both  of  these inhibiting  conditions
>   may be true, thereby seriously disfavoring appearance of gustatory or 
>   olfactory sensations during dreaming

#### References

- ANTONIO, L.Z. and Nielsen, T.A. and Donderi, DC. (1998). Prevalence of auditory, olfactory, and gustatory experiences in home dreams. Perceptual and motor skills, 87, 3, 819-826.[PDF](http://www.dreamscience.ca/en/documents/publications/_1998_Nielsen_Zadra_Reprint_PMS_87_819-826_experiences_home_dreams.pdf)
- Carrasco,  M.,  & Ridout,  J. B. (1997)  Olfactory perception and olfactory imagery: a multidimensional analysis. Journal  0f Experimental Psychology: Human Perception &  Performance,
  19,287-30l.
- Drummond,  P. D. (1995)  Effect of imagining and actually tasting a sour taste on one side of the tongue. Physiology & Behavior, 57, 373-376.
- Herz, R. S, & Engen,  T. (1996)  Odor memory: review and analysis. Psychonomic Bulletin & Review, 3, 300-313
- Lyman, B. J., & McDaniel. M. A. (1986)  Effects  of  encoding  strategy  on  long-term  memory  for
  odours. Human memory. Quarterly Journal of Experimental  Psychology: A-Human  Experimental Psychology, 38(4-A), 753-765.
- Steriade,  M.  (1994)  Brain electrical  activity and sensory processing during waking and sleep states. In  M.  H. Kryger, T. Roth, &  W. C. Dement (Eds.), Principles and practice of sleep medicine. (2nd ed.) Philadelphia, FA: Saunders. pp.  105-124.

Answer (score 5):

Also, in Oliver Sack's *The Man Who Mistook His For His Wife*, the author and famous neurologist reports a case about a man who dreamed he had the olfactory powers of a dog; however, when he awoke, he still retained his heightened sense of smell and furthermore could prove it to the nurses.

Any experience that one has in waking life can be recapitulated during a dream. In addition, [Anthony Wagner](http://www.stanford.edu/group/memorylab/Publications/Publications.html) has a line of research investigating how rehearsal and learning mechanisms operate during sleep. It is unclear at this point how much novel learning can occur during sleep, as no paradigm has demonstrated this very successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I had a novel dreaming experience last night that led me to this website.  I was having a dream revolving around plastic waste!  I think this was recapitulating a discussion my wife and I had recently had about the problems of coping with the changing rules and options for dealing with domestic recycling of plastic. The content of the dream seems trivial and disorganized now, but one component was vivid and unusual.

In the dream, I set fire to some plastic waste and smelled an acrid, unpleasant odor of burning plastic.  The odor sensation was VERY vivid, almost overpowering. Immediately upon registering this odor sensation, I began to be aware of the rousing of my "conscious", rational mind, which was immediately gripped by the thought of "FIRE!".

I awoke with a start and with the thought that something was burning in the house.  However, after a breath two of air passed through my nose, I calmed down, as the air in my bedroom was clear and odor free.  The sensation had been so vivid, however, that I could not get back to sleep until I had roused myself and walked around a bit to assure myself that nothing was burning, and that there was no lingering scent of burning plastic in my house.

I can't say that I can recall ever experiencing such a vivid odor, indeed ANY vivid odor, in a dream before this.